# Como completar este codigo de Queues?

Tags: javascript

Estoy ejercitándome para introducirme en el mundo de la programación y no encuentro como comenzar este ejercicio. Si pudiesen ayudarme a resolverlo, o explicarme por donde deberia empezar les agradeceria mucho. Gracias!

EJERCICIO 6

Implementar la función controlAcces: a partir de una Queue que va a recibir como paráemtro que tiene
en cada posición un objeto que va a representar a una persona y tiene la siguiente forma:

```
 // {
    //   fullname: "Franco Etcheverri",
    //   age: 26,
    //   ticket: {
    //     number: 1,
    //     event: "Tomorrowland"
    //   }
    // }
```

La idea es ir verificando uno a uno si la primer persona de la cola tiene los requisitos necesarios para
ingresar al evento correspondiente (también recibido por parámetro). Los requisitos que debe cumplir son:

- Ser mayor de 18 años (18 inclusive es válido)
- Tener un ticket que corresponda con el evento (prop event de ticket)
- Que no haya ingresado ya otra persona al evento con ese mismo número de ticket
  Finalmente la función debe devolver un arreglo con todos los nombres de las personas que pudieron ingresar
  Importante!: Aquellas personas que no cumplan con los requisitos para ingresar deben ser removidos de la cola

var controlAcces = function(queue, event){
Tu código aca:

}

Answer (score 0):

Te lo explico todo en el ejercicio que hice, tuve que añadir mas personas a la ecuación porque sino no se vería el proceso de selección:

```js
    document.body.innerHTML = '';

    //Lo primero crear un Array de objetos con varios participantes en el proceso
    //Sino, no tiene sentido hacer un control de acceso

    let users = [
        user("Franco Ercheverri", 26, 1, "Tomorrowland"),//Pasamos como parametro todos los datos a través de la función user
        user("Pancracio Monasegui", 17, 2, "NoMorrowland"),
        user("Pancracio Monasegui", 18, 1, "Tomorrowland"),
        user("Yo", 25, 553, "Tomorrowland"),
        user("Tu", 65, 553, "Tomorrowland"),
        user("Correcto", 20, 999, "Tomorrowland"),
        user("Incorrecto", 20, 1, "Tomorrowland"),
        user("Correcto 2", 53, 500, "Tomorrowland")
    ]
//Ahora tenemos 3 usuarios, vamos con el control access

    function user(name, age, id, event){//recogemos todos los parametros y hacemos un return con los datos
        return {
            fullname : name,//fullname será el nombre del parametro DENTRO del objeto, mientras que name es el nombre de la variable pasada como parametro
            age : age,
            "ticket" : {//Aquí se hace un poco más compleja la sintaxis porque se tiene que poner "ticket" para comenzar un nuevo objeto dentro del objeto
                number : id,//pero igualmente es sencillo
                event : event
            }
        }
    }

    //llamamos a la funcion eliminarDuplicados con el array de objetos mandado como parametro
    let usr = eliminarDuplicados(users); // y le agregamos el resultado de todo a usr
    controlAccess(usr);//y mandamos usr (que es un array) a conrtolAccess, donde se hara una segunda criba

function eliminarDuplicados(usr){
    let ary = [];//inicializamos un segundo array, para concesiones
    
    const repeticiones={};//inicializamos un objeto nuevo, para exclusiones
    
    usr.forEach((elemento,posicion)=>{//hacemos un recorrido indicando elemento y posicion
        repeticiones[elemento.ticket.number] = repeticiones[elemento.ticket.number] || [];
        //metemos dentro de repeticiones el elemento O no agregamos nada, así solamente creamos duplicidad
        repeticiones[elemento.ticket.number].push(posicion);
        //y metemos la posición dentro de repeticiones
    });

    return usr.filter(elemento=>{//retornamos lo que haga el filter del array

        const posiciones = repeticiones[elemento.ticket.number];//donde posiciones sere equivalente al objeto repeticion

            if (posiciones.length > 1) {//si es mayor que uno, retornara falso
                return false;//por tanto sera eliminado
            }

        ary.push(elemento);//metemos todos los elementos que queden, los que no hayan sido excluidos dentro de ary
        //recordemos que ary es el array inicializado para concesiones
        
        return ary // y retornamos el valor de ary, osea, el array completo
    });
}


function controlAccess(usr){//recibimos el valor de ary, al que llamaremos usr, por comlpicarme mas la vida
    //y porque tengo serior problemas mentales
    
    const usuariosFiltrados = usr.filter(item=>{//hacemos otro filtro al array, donde solamente nos hara falta indicar el elemento, e este caso
        //llamado item
        
        if (item.age >= 18 || item.ticket.event == "Tomorrowland"){//hacemos la criba positiva, es decir
            //si tiene igual o mas de 18 de edad
            //si su nombre de evento es literalmente "Tomorowland"
            console.log(item.fullname +': Acceso permitido');//hacemos un acceso permitido
            return true;//retornamos true, por tanto, adicionar al array usr, que en realidad es ary
            //ves como me gusta complicarme?
        }
    });

    console.log(usuariosFiltrados);//y vemos el resultado final solamente con los usuarios que cumplan dichas caracteristicas

    //en un principio se hizo con que uno de los dos usuarios con id duplicado entrase, pero siendo sincero
    //un programa no puede determinar quien miente o dice la verdad, por tanto, se eliminan los dos
    //y el que tenga quejas que reclame
}
```

Todo esto no hubiera sido gracias a @Pablo Lozano, que me ayudó a hacer la criba muchísimo, porque yo solo conseguía que entrase uno de los duplicados.

Comment: Una pregunta, ese codigo no funcionaria unicamente en caso de que siempre pasen el valor de tomorrowland? Si quisieran darnos otro evento y que fuese valido, no se podria verdad?

Comment: Si quieres poner otro evento válido, entonces solo tienes que añadir el or (||) item.ticket.event == "Eventovalido2" dentro del if y ya estaría, osea:

  if (item.age >= 18 || item.ticket.event == "Tomorrowland" || item.ticket.event == "lo que sea"){
            console.log(item.fullname +': Acceso permitido');
            return true;
        }

Comment: Y si quisiera que ese evento se elija pasandoselo? Digamos, que el programa me pida que ingrese que evento es el valido y que segun lo que ingrese haga el control o no.

Comment: con un prompt como variable, `let nombre_evento_valido = prompt('Ingresa el nombre del evento')` y luego aplicar la logica anterior, `if(item.ticket.evento == nombre_evento_valido)`